# Problem with minecraft server running on 64-bit Windows 7 computer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

I downloaded minecraft_server.jar from [here](http://www.minecraft.net/download.jsp), and made run.bat which content is

`java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui`.

It runs well, I can connect with typing my IP, but my friend (Windows Vista - 32bit) couldn't connect to my server, even though he can connect to my Apache web server. (**not** the connection problem)

We had this problem months ago, and somebody told us the 32bit side (my friend) should open the server, and it worked.

However, my friends said to me that his computer is cr*p, so he can't run minecraft server well and asked me to find the way running minecraft server...

How to fix this problem - 32bit computer can't connect to 64bit minecraft server?

Comment: Have you tried using 32 bit Java? I've done this (64bit server PC with 32 bit connecting people).

Comment: how did you configure the network settings for minecraft? is there a firewall?

Comment: @bckbck : I didn't check... I'll do @The Communist Duck's method and check network settings if that method doesn't work..

Comment: whose method worked? so i/him can write our answers if it is correct, and you can mark the answer as correct

Comment: @bckbck : Communist Duck's method. I downloaded 32 bit version and it worked.

Comment: then, when he writes his answer, make sure you mark it as correct.

Comment: @Matthew Read even with spaces, you need the full name ;-)

Comment: @JiminP just a reminder - mark his question as correct!

Comment: @The Communist Duck: That's weird, because I get notifications when just my first name or even "Matt" is used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download 32-bit Java and use that for the server.